# Trigger BackgroundTask by calender events

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Imagine a background task being registered to get triggered at a calender event (event from the build-in calender) from a **Windows Phone 8.1** app. What are the possibilities for doing so?

As far as I prototyped it it is not possible to subscribe for the notifications. The only possibility I see is to copy all calender events at background task registration and let them sit in some owned cloud service that pushes raw notifications (raw notifications are very important) to my background task from **WNS** which requires internet connection which again is impractical. Moreover the service is required to be placed in lock screen. There are so many problems with synchronizing the calendar events if you think about it too.

The solution I would like to implement however should not require internet connection. How can I simplify it?

For more information on background tasks please visit https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/11/08/background-tasks-myths-and-realities/

Comment: What events are you imaging? Idk what I should imaging, maybe a simple notification about a near event? Beside that, could you maybe link where you got your information from? That would save time. At least, if nobody minds your question here try the other website 
"Windows Phone beta" on stack exchange :)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your interest. I am potentially interested in all events from the build-in calender. Notifications that I would like to receive should not be visible by the user - so called 'raw notifications' are for that purpose. More information can be found here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/11/08/background-tasks-myths-and-realities/